# Numpy doesn't work with virtual env (django)

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv

I setup my **virtual env** with `pip install virtualenv`

Then actiavte it with `.\env\Scripts\activate`

When i try to import **numpy** in my `views.py` i get this error

[image: Error]

If i switch to Python global the import works but i can't run the server

[image]

When i use `pip install numpy` after activating **virtual env** i get this error.

```
path...\env\Scripts\pip.exe" install numpy': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found solution: `python -m pip install [module name]`